# Mysqli better way to change what column working with?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So my code needs to have a weight tracker and need to keep at least 20 weights in one data point. Because I can not dynamically change it with "?" the location I have 20 if () else if statements to be able to do the same thing. Was just wondering is there a better way to do this or is this the only way to do this?

Begining of code:

```
function addWeight($conn, $location, $weight,$dt){
//select the two variables changing 
if($location == "Weight1"){
    $sql ="UPDATE userweight SET Weight1=? WHERE userId = ?;";
    $sql2 ="UPDATE userweight SET timee1=? WHERE userId = ?;";
}elseif($location == "Weight2"){
    $sql ="UPDATE userweight SET Weight2=? WHERE userId = ?;";
    $sql2 ="UPDATE userweight SET timee2=? WHERE userId = ?;";
}elseif($location == "Weight3"){
    $sql ="UPDATE userweight SET Weight3=? WHERE userId = ?;";
    $sql2 ="UPDATE userweight SET timee3=? WHERE userId = ?;";
}elseif($location == "Weight4"){
    $sql ="UPDATE userweight SET Weight4=? WHERE userId = ?;";
    $sql2 ="UPDATE userweight SET timee4=? WHERE userId = ?;";
}
.....
```

Comment: You need to normalize your database. Your column names should never have numbers in them.

Comment: Ok. Will normalizing it allow me to do something else other than these 20 if else if statements or is that just a database standard?    And how would I normalize it?

Comment: Normalization is how storing the data in the database in a proper way. RDBMS are designed to stored the data with relations. You don't create multiple columns with similar names, instead you create connected table. It makes searching faster and easier.

Comment: Ok, that sounds very interesting and useful. I will have to do more research into that. Thanks @Dharman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the data like this. This is just asking for problems. Instead normalize your schema and store the data in a relational way.

If you are stuck with the current design, you can overcome this problem by building the SQL dynamically. Be sure to validate with hardcoded list of values that the column name is correct.

```
function addWeight(mysqli $conn, $location, $weight, $dt)
{
    $columns = [
        "Weight1" => 'timee1',
        "Weight2" => 'timee2',
        "Weight3" => 'timee3',
        "Weight4" => 'timee4',
    ];
    if (!isset($columns[$location])) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Invalid location");
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE userweight SET {$location}=? WHERE userId = ?;";
    $sql2 = "UPDATE userweight SET {$columns[$location]}=? WHERE userId = ?;";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using two tables, and change location to only a number:

```
Table 1: userweight
userId | location_nr | weight |
   1    |      1      |  60    |
   1    |      8      |  93    |

Table 2: usertime
userId | location_nr | time           |
   1    |      1      |  2020-05-03    |
   1    |      8      |  2020-09-18    |
```

Now based on the user_id and location, you can use queries like:

```
UPDATE userweight SET weight = ? WHERE userId = ? and location_nr= ?
UPDATE usertime SET timee= ? WHERE userId = ? and location_nr= ?
```